# SQL query made up of 2 subqueries

Tags: sql, oracle, sas

I have a problem with SQL. I'm used to coding in SAS and being able to create intermediate tables on which to perform operations/modifications.
Except that I have to use SQL Developer on Oracle databases, with **a single query**.

I want to **combine 2 queries** (below) into one, **with an INNER JOIN** to retrieve the common rows and variables from the 2 tables as the final output.

I really don't see how to do this. Thank you for your help.

Query 1 :

```
select A.*, B.var1, B.var2, B.var3, B.var4, B.var5, B.var6 as new_var6, B.var7,
    case
        when a.var1 = 'thing' then CONCAT(B.var4,A.var1)
        else CONCAT(b.var7,A.var1)
    end as key_second_join,
    1 as var8
from bibliotheque.BASE_A A
inner join bibliotheque.BASE_B B
on A.key_first_join = B.var1
order by A.key_first_join;
```

Query 2 :

```
SELECT T.*, CONCAT(C_VAR1,C_VAR3) key_second_join
FROM (
    SELECT *
        FROM bibliotheque2.BASE_C
        WHERE (C_VAR1, C_VAR2) IN (
            SELECT C_VAR1, MAX(C_VAR2)
            FROM bibliotheque2.BASE_C
            GROUP BY C_VAR1)) T;
```

I've tried a large query but always get errors like : 'missing right parenthesis', 'column ambiguously defined'

The goal of the big query is to have the result of this :

```
select *
from query1 as t2
inner join query2 as t1 on t1.key_second_join=t2.key_second_join;
run;
```

---

*EDIT :*
Thank you very much for your answers.
I used solution 1, with sub-query and `WITH` clause. As I was effectively blocked by the ORA-00918 error, I changed all the table prefixes in the `SELECT` clauses. But I still get the same error, despite the changes :

```
WITH QUERY1 AS (
    SELECT 
    A.VARA1,
    A.VARA2,
    A.VARA3,
    A.VARA4,
    A.VAR5,
    A.VARA6,
    A.VARA7,
    A.VARA8,
    A.VARA9,
    B.VARB1,
    B.VARB2,
    B.VARB3,
    B.VARB4, 
    B.VAR5,
    CASE
        WHEN A.VARA2 = '11307' THEN CONCAT(B.VARB3,A.VARA2)
        ELSE CONCAT(B.VARB4,A.VARA2)
    END AS KEY_SECOND_JOIN_T1,
    1 as VAR10
    FROM BIBLIOTHEQUE.BASE_A A
        INNER JOIN BIBLIOTHEQUE.BASE_B B
        ON A.VAR5 = B.VAR5
        /*ORDER BY A.CT_CAUTION*/
),
QUERY2 AS (
    SELECT 
    C.VARC1,
    C.VARC2,
    C.VARC3,
    C.VARC4,
    CONCAT(VARC1,VARC2) KEY_SECOND_JOIN_T2
    FROM BIBLIOTHEQUE2.BASE_C C
    WHERE(VARC1, VARC3)
        IN(
            SELECT D.VARC1, MAX(D.VARC3)
            FROM BIBLIOTHEQUE2.BASE_C D
            GROUP BY VARC1)
)
SELECT 
    T1.VAR10,
    T1.KEY_SECOND_JOIN_T1,
    T1.VARA1,
    T1.VARA2,
    T1.VARA3,
    T1.VARA4,
    T1.VAR5,
    T1.VARA6,
    T1.VARA7,
    T1.VARA8,
    T1.VARA9,
    T1.VARB1, 
    T1.VARB2,
    T1.VARB3,
    T1.VARB4, 
    T2.KEY_SECOND_JOIN_T2,
    T2.VARC1,
    T2.VARC2,
    T2.VARC3,
    T2.VARC4
    FROM QUERY1 T1
        INNER JOIN QUERY2 T2
        ON T1.KEY_SECOND_JOIN_T1=T2.KEY_SECOND_JOIN_T2
;
```

Comment: You should be able to fix the unbalanced () yourself.  To fix the other issue always use table references when mentioning columns.  For example which usage of BASE_C is C_VAR1 coming from in your second sub-query?

Comment: @Tom Agreed, column aliases should be used for clarity. To answer your question, values will always be taken from the local scope in preference to any surrounding (outer) scope (if there is a table alias prefix then that should determine the scope - again preferring local scope for the table alias over an outer scope).

Comment: Thank you both, I've taken note of your advice and your answers. I've edited the post, because even though I've specified all the bases in the Select clause, the error remains.

Comment: @JH `SELECT ..., A.VAR5, ..., B.VAR5 ...` you have two columns both named `VAR5` you need to alias one (or both) of them to something else `SELECT ..., A.VAR5 AS VARA5, ..., B.VAR5 AS VARB5 ...` and then in the later query you can use `SELECT ... T1.VARA5, T1.VARB5, ...`. Alternatively, only select one of `A.VAR5` and `B.VAR5` in the first query.

Answer (score 2):

Use a sub-query factoring clause (`WITH`):

```sql
WITH query1 AS (
  select A.*, B.var1, B.var2, B.var3, B.var4, B.var5, B.var6 as new_var6, B.var7,
         CASE a.var1 WHEN 'thing' THEN B.var4 ELSE b.var7 END
           || A.var1 AS key_second_join,
         1 as var8
  from   bibliotheque.BASE_A A
         inner join bibliotheque.BASE_B B
         on A.key_first_join = B.var1
),
query2 AS (
  SELECT T.*,
         C_VAR1 || C_VAR3 AS key_second_join
  FROM   bibliotheque2.BASE_C t
  WHERE  (C_VAR1, C_VAR2) IN ( SELECT C_VAR1, MAX(C_VAR2)
                               FROM bibliotheque2.BASE_C
                               GROUP BY C_VAR1)
)
select *
from   query1 t2
       inner join query2 t1
       on t1.key_second_join=t2.key_second_join;
```

*(and, in Oracle, `AS` before a table alias is forbidden so `query1 as t2` should be `query1 t2`.)*

If you have duplicate column identifiers (i.e. if `BASE_A`, `BASE_B` or `BASE_C` contain columns with the same names) then you will need to explicitly include all the columns in the `SELECT` clause and give them distinct column aliases rather than using `SELECT *` or `SELECT A.*`.

---

Alternatively, combine the two `SELECT`s into one:

```sql
select A.*,
       B.var1, B.var2, B.var3, B.var4, B.var5, B.var6 as new_var6, B.var7,
       CASE a.var1 WHEN 'thing' THEN B.var4 ELSE b.var7 END
         || A.var1 AS key_second_join,
       1 as var8,
       C.*
FROM   bibliotheque.BASE_A A
       INNER JOIN bibliotheque.BASE_B B
       ON A.key_first_join = B.var1
       INNER JOIN bibliotheque2.BASE_C C
       ON CASE a.var1 WHEN 'thing' THEN B.var4 ELSE b.var7 END || A.var1
          = c.C_VAR1 || c.C_VAR3
WHERE  (C.C_VAR1, C.C_VAR2) IN ( SELECT C_VAR1, MAX(C_VAR2)
                                 FROM bibliotheque2.BASE_C
                                 GROUP BY C_VAR1 )
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the word `as` when aliasing a table (or subquery in your case). The example query below should work.

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT a.*,
               b.var1,
               b.var2,
               b.var3,
               b.var4,
               b.var5,
               b.var6                                                                                       AS new_var6,
               b.var7,
               CASE WHEN a.var1 = 'thing' THEN CONCAT (b.var4, a.var1) ELSE CONCAT (b.var7, a.var1) END     AS key_second_join,
               1                                                                                            AS var8
          FROM bibliotheque.base_a a INNER JOIN bibliotheque.base_b b ON a.key_first_join = b.var1) t2
       JOIN (SELECT t.*, CONCAT (c_var1, c_var3) key_second_join
               FROM (SELECT *
                       FROM bibliotheque2.base_c
                      WHERE (c_var1, c_var2) IN (  SELECT c_var1, MAX (c_var2)
                                                     FROM bibliotheque2.base_c
                                                 GROUP BY c_var1)) t) t1
           ON (t1.key_second_join = t2.key_second_join);
```